# Feature selection in an SVM classifier

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, svm

I'm preparing a program to detect and recognize road signs in images. I am currently creating an SVM classifier which distinguishes circles from rectangles. For this purpose I'm using a feature vector with 7 Hu moments. Unfortunately, the moments I get are too divergent, so I have to choose only those which are similar to each other.
Below you can find part of my script.

```css
 training_mat_norm = training_mat_norm.reshape(1, 27);
    int l_wierszy = training_mat_norm.rows;
    Mat etykieta = (Mat_<int>(l_wierszy,1, CV_32SC1) << -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

   
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::POLY;
    params.degree = 3;
    params.gamma = 3;
    params.C = 3;
 
    CvSVM svm;
    svm.train(training_mat_norm, etykieta, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

training_mat_norm is a matrix containing the calculated Hu moments of 27 
[base signs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NThzH.jpg)

Does anybody know how to perform feature selection?

Comment: My real suggestion would be to build a Hough transform or use one of many other more constructively robust methods to recognize these simple shapes, but if you're set on an SVM there are automatic ways of selecting features, I think reading this classifyhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio, won't hurt

Comment: I can't use Hough transform, because my program detects signs in blurred and contaminated images, so sometimes their shape isn't entirely visible. I am not looking for other way. I want to solve issue regarding feature selection. In my script I also can't use automatic selection which SVM classifier offers.